# Google fit aggregate limit of 90 days

Tags: google-fit

I have understood that there is a limit of 90 days when trying to fetch aggregated data (Google fit heart points). I know that since a request of more than 90 days fails. But it would be great if someone could point me to a documentation somewhere that defines this limit. I have tried and failed to find.

Thanks & Regards,
Chitra

Comment: It is not currently officially documented, but I can confirm that there is a ~90-day limit (precisely, it's a 90*24*60*60*1000=7776000000ms limit). I've added it to the public documentation, it will be [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataset/aggregate), but cannot say when that will be updated.

Comment: It would be great if it makes it to the documentation. But thank you for clarifying.