# What is the limit on the number of days I could use to do aggregated data fetch from google fit history api

Tags: android, google-fit

I am fetching aggregated data (24hr/1 day buckets) from google fit. I am looking to find the limit on max numbers of days i could use to fetch aggregated data in a single history api call. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250923/google-fit-aggregate-limit-of-90-days) from 2 years ago suggests 90 days but couldn't seem to find any official documentation on it.